# clicked UIBarButtonItem side menu not open

Tags: ios

I am developing iOS App.Add UIBarButtonItem on Custom UIView.Button Added Successfully.But, when I click on button enter on selector action.But Side menu not open. Please Help thanks in Advance.

```
- (void)sideButton{
        UIImage *menuButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"];// set your image Name here
        UIButton *btnToggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnToggle setImage:menuButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnToggle addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnToggle.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 25, 25);
        [_sideView addSubview:btnToggle]; //sideView is UIView

        _menuBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnToggle];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _menuBarButton;
    }
    - (IBAction)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender{
        SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
        if ( revealViewController ){
            [_menuBarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
            [_menuBarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
            [self.view 
        addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
        }
    }
```

Comment: the checkButtonTapped is called or not

Comment: try to follow this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ step by step guide. it should work if you implement it the right way as described

Comment: try to follow this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ step by step guide. it should work if you implement it the right way as described

Comment: checkButtonTapped is Called

Comment: Using SWReveal side NavigationBar. but click on side barButton called This checkButtonTapped.but Not Open Side bar